# what's the difference between usages of ''ahead'' in these sentences?

Tags: meaning, difference

here are two examples

> - 3 big reasons why Barack Obama will be remembered as **ahead of** his    time
> - can you tell me **ahead of** time if you're coming?

one of them means **after** and one of them means **before**. I know president Obama has left his office. I thought that It means after his time.

How can I figure out whether ahead means **after** or **before**?

Comment: *Will be remembered as ahead of his time* doesn't mean *will be remembered after his presidency term*. Cookie Monster got it right in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example:

> 3 big reasons why Barack Obama will be **remembered as ahead of his time**

I think what this sentence really says is that Obama is going to be remembered as a person who was ahead of his time. He is not going to be remembered before he is dead or anything like that. They just shortened *a person who was ahead of his time* to *ahead of his time*. So, *ahead of* has only one meaning: before something happens. How can it possibly mean the opposite?